# Mac Powerpoint addins?

Tags: c#, macos, dll, add-in, powerpoint

Currently we have a DLL Windows Powerpoint addin written in C#.

Is there anyway to translate that into the Mac version of Powerpoint? Obviously DLL doesn't exist on Macs, so what would be an alternative? What programming language would I have to write it in? is there a way to automatically convert?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

No need for AppleScript.

Office 2011 for Mac is out already, and does support VBA (and hence add-ins) once again, with some nice improvements over the earlier VBA support that was offered in pre-2008 versions of Mac Office.

Probably the simplest thing will be to translate from C# to VBA and get it working on a Windows box.

In theory, you can write add-ins on a PC and install them on Mac but that's a lousy theory. Close, but no cigar.

However, it's a lot easier to write the stuff on a PC, get it debugged, then move it to the Mac for further testing and debugging.

Compatibility is a lot better than it's ever been in the past but still leaves a lot to be desired, and if you're used to the Windows VB/VBA IDEs, the Mac version will make you crazy.

You'll want to assume that all dialog boxes will need to be rewritten on the Mac.  Dlgs from the Windows VBA versions work, but look like dog's breakfast on the Mac.  Export any code in your dialogs as modules or text files, re-create the dialog on the Mac, then bring the code back in.

Obviously, you can't include any Win API code and expect it to work on the Mac, and there will be differences in the way some of the VBA commands work.

I haven't tested this in 2011 but in previous versions, you could call AppleScript to do things that you'd use WinAPI calls for on a Windows box, file dialogs and such.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aSgpufhsWK7EJ%3awww.officeformac.com/ms/ProductForums/PowerPoint/3693%20Mac%20powerpoint%20add-ins&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca&source=www.google.ca) has information which may be useful to you. From what it appears it seems that you'll need to use AppleScript to create addins but you must be familiar with the Office Object Model. Support for addins is supposedly coming to v2011.

My apologies if this information isn't helpful. Documentation for Mac addins is sketchy as I'm sure you're aware.