# Can you write a C# Excel add-in with Visual Studio 2010 for the Mac?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have Windows 7 and would be writing it in Visual Studio. I have done this for other Windows computers, but have never tried to deploy to a Mac before. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VSTO for the Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324439/vsto-for-the-mac)

Comment: How do you plan to run C# on your Mac ?

Comment: Take a look to this post here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522989/mac-powerpoint-addins

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the problem isn't .NET (there is Mono) but interop with Office.